# What does “fresh-off-the-vine technologies” mean?

Tags: phrases, compound-adjectives

Time magazine (February 11) carries an article reviewing the fast evolution of drone technology and problems and opportunities involved with President Obama’s “drone campaign”, under the title *[Drone Home](http://www.time.com/time/magazine/article/0,9171,2135132,00.html)*.

It says:

> Five years ago the Parrot (drone) couldn’t have existed; it’s an
>   anthology of **fresh-off-the-vine technologies**. Five years ago there
>   weren’t cameras as tiny and sharp or chips as tiny and fast.

As I did not find the phrase “fresh-off-the-vine” in any English dictionaries at hand, I checked the phrase online to find only irrelevant lines such as:

> Ask the guys from Fresh Off the Vine what kind of music they play, and the first word that comes to mind is “mystical.” - www.dailyinterlake.com

Though I surmise that “fresh-off-the vine technologies” means just newly born technologies (please correct me, if I’m wrong), is the phrase, “fresh-off-the-vine” widely and frequently used to imply "fledgling" or "brand new"? Can I say 'fresh-off style / fashion / idea etc' in the same way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, "fresh off the vine" means brand new, the very latest thing.

It suggests picking a very fresh grape directly from the vine where it grows: you can't get fresher or newer.

America's drones are an amalgamation of new tech: unmanned, remotely-piloted aircraft with the very latest autostabilisation, rotors and cameras.

Comment: It's possibly also a play on the etymology of _anthology_.